# Why is my background-color not working in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

The `background-color` CSS property in Chrome is not working when I implement it into the body. However, when I test it in CodePen, the body's background color changes accordingly. Here is the link to the CodePen code: https://codepen.io/Ag_Yog/pen/rzezYw.

Here is the code that does not work in notepad:

HTML:

```html
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container quoteCard">
            <p id="quote" class= "text">Txt</p>
            <button class = "btn getQuote ">Get new Quote</button>
    </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
</body>
```

CSS:

```css
 html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #00e676 ;

}

.quoteCard{
    background-color: #fff176;
}

.text{
    position: relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-family: 'Acme', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

When inspecting the code on Google Chrome, it shows that there is no background-color, even though I specified it in the CSS:

[image: blank background-color declaration]

Comment: You save this code with which extension? .html?

Comment: When you inspect the element `body` are you seeing the `background-color` style rule, and if so, is it being over-qualified by another style rule?

Comment: Try a hard refresh. CTRL + F5

Comment: "code that does not work in notepad"... ok. Did you try to swap bootstrap.css and main.css ?

Comment: Well, to start, setting a height of 100% is not going to make the page 100% of the viewport.  I can't tell for sure without your html, but one solution is to use "height:100vh;". This will fill the entire viewport.

Comment: I saved it as .html

Comment: Also, try adding your custom external stylesheet `main.css` below the  `bootstrap.min.css` external cdn - could be a simple cascading order issue, although no way to know for sure without more information.

Comment: So you tested your code out in other browsers and Chrome is the lone culprit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bootstrap's background color is overwriting your main.css so the background-color property is taken from the bootstrap css file. Change the order of your css files.

```
    <html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Acme" rel="stylesheet">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container quoteCard">
            <p id="quote" class= "text">Txt</p>
            <button class = "btn getQuote ">Get new Quote</button>
    </div>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This will work

Answer (score 1):

I found I was having the same issue when using all of the CSS code for the body tag. I removed the background-color tag from that grouping and put it into a separate grouping for the same tag and everything worked as intended. It's an organizational problem, but it is functional.
Here's the example from my code (This is in my main.css file):

```
<style>

    body {
        font-family: Trebuchet MS;
        margin-left: autopx;
        margin-right: autopx;
        margin-bottom: autopx;
        margin-top: autopx;
    }

    body {background-color: #242424;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case some lost soul happens to be struggling with the same thing I was, and their search ends up here...  I found that my background-color style was being applied if placed inline in the html file, but not from the css file, because the css file was apparently not getting updated. When I enabled chrome cache killer extension, life was good again.

Answer (score 0):

On codepen the body is already responsive, whereas your Chrome's page needs to be made responsive to react to the `%` of your CSS Properties.

Add these meta tags-

`<head>
<meta name="viewport"content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="viewport"content="height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>`

Now your webpage can detect the devices width and height and set the style attributes according to them.

However, if this still doesn't work. Change your `height` properties value from `100%` to something specific with `px` or use `em` if you want it to be responsive with different devices DPR.